# How to convert pure java String which includes groovy expression in runtime?

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

Let's say if we defined property value which includes groovy expression in gradle.properties file:

```
databaseFile = ${System.properties['user.home']}/.derby
```

Later when I want to access this property value in gradle build script, 
it seems that it was loaded as pure java String in groovy runtime without string evaluation.

Are there any methods that could help me evaluate pure java String before I get the property value via gradle dsl? 
Or I have to evaluate the java String I've got in runtime? But how to make that?

Thank you~

Comment: Can't you just do `databaseFile = "${System.properties['user.home']}/.derby"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

```
databaseFile_unevaluated = '${System.properties[\'user.home\']}/.derby'
```

You might be able to evaluate it as a `GString` using [`Eval`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/Eval.html):

```
databaseFile = Eval.me(""" "$databaseFile_unevaluated" """)
```

This could also be written as:

```
databaseFile = Eval.me("\"$databaseFile_unevaluated\"")
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much! Can you teach me how to interpret the argument of Eval.me? I haven't seen this type of string expression in groovy docs.
I've try to use Eval.me many times to resolve this issue but all failed.

Comment: Sure, I'll explain a bit more.  It's quite weird though, and I'm surprised I couldn't find a clearer path to instantiating `GString` or `GStringImpl`

Comment: `"""` is a way of declaring a multi-line `GString`.  Conveniently, this allows us to include the `"` character within a GString, which means we can pass the following to `Eval.me()`: `\"${System.properties['user.home']}/.derby\"`, so `Eval` can process this as a `GString`.

Comment: Just a regular note to use caution with `Eval.me`, arbitrarily running user input isn't recommended

Comment: for this context the other quote variants are quite helpful: single quotes, slashed quotes, dollar-slash quotes - this will ease coding a lot.